# Data challenge - postgres sql - Numbering timefollowing events

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset in which I want to generate a new id that combines timeupfollowing events. So if one row has an endtime the same as the next starttime, plus the firstid is the same and the secondid follows up the last one, it should generate a same 'newid' for both. I took a small sample of the data here:

```
firstid secondid starttime              endtime             stage
13123   010      2017-10-15  11:31:16   2017-10-15 11:36:34 1
13123   011      2017-10-15  11:36:34   2017-10-15 11:45:31 2
13123   021      2017-10-16  09:15:16   2017-10-16 09:55:43 1
13123   022      2017-10-16  09:55:43   2017-10-16 10:45:31 2
20314   010      2017-10-18  17:24:16   2017-10-18 17:46:34 1
20314   011      2017-10-18  17:46:34   2017-10-18 18:10:31 2
```

I want to transform it into:

```
firstid secondid starttime           endtime           stage  newid
13123   010      2017-10-15 11:31:16 2017-10-15 11:36:34 1    1
13123   011      2017-10-15 11:36:34 2017-10-15 11:45:31 2    1
13123   021      2017-10-16 09:15:16 2017-10-16 09:55:43 1    2
13123   022      2017-10-16 09:55:43 2017-10-16 10:45:31 2    2
20314   010      2017-10-18 17:24:16 2017-10-18 17:46:34 1    3
20314   011      2017-10-18 17:46:34 2017-10-18 18:10:31 2    3
```

Seems doable but cant get it done. Can anyone help me out?

EDIT 1; Think I got it; round second id to form a new column and then group by that new column! Testing now.

EDIT 2; Solution does not work; Found out the secondid is not as logical as I thought. There is structure in there as follows:

```
13123   010      2017-10-15  11:31:16   2017-10-15 11:36:34 1
13123   011      2017-10-15  11:36:34   2017-10-15 11:45:31 2
13123   012      2017-10-16  09:15:16   2017-10-16 09:55:43 1
13123   021      2017-10-16  09:55:43   2017-10-16 10:45:31 2
```

Comment: It will always be a pair of events or there can be any number of consecutive events?

Comment: There can be a number of consecutive events. Also more trips on one day

Answer (score 0):

You may try something along these lines:

```
with borders as (
    select case when lag(endtime) over (partition by firstid order by starttime) = starttime then 0 else 1 end sep, *
    from data
),
dataRn as
(
    select row_number() over (partition by firstid, sep order by starttime) grNo,
       *
    from borders
    where sep = 1
)
select *
from
(
    select firstid, secondid, starttime, endtime, grNo
    from dataRn
    union all
    select firstid, secondid, starttime, endtime, 
           (select max(grno) from dataRn t2 where t2.firstid = t1.firstid and t2.endtime <= t1.starttime) grno
    from borders t1
    where sep = 0
) t
order by firstid, starttime
```

[DBFiddle DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f032b527dd04eaa74b75a7ed263f6ac2)

The solution assumes that the intervals of one `firstid` do not overlap!